# Elastic search - need common tags from different fields

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm using Elastic Search trying to get the count of each "tags" for a set of questions,  Here's a rough picture of the mapping:

schoolId

schoolname

question1

```
       tags(array) 
                  tagId , tagStr
                  tagid , tagStr
                  tagid , tagStr
```

question2

```
       tags(array) 
                  tagId , tagStr
                  tagid , tagStr
                  tagid , tagStr
```

question3

```
       tags(array) 
                  tagId , tagStr
                  tagid , tagStr
                  tagid , tagStr
```

now i need the top common tags from all three fields (question1,question2,question3)

like this

tagStr : clean ,doc_count :6

tagStr : faculty,doc_count :4

tagStr : study,doc_count :2

i am using aggregation on this provided by elastic search . like this

```
"aggs": {
      "Question1_TAGS": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "question1.tags.tagStr",
            "size": 3
         }
      },
      "Question2_TAGS": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "question2.tags.tagStr",
            "size": 3
         }
      },
      "Question3_TAGS": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "question3.tags.tagStr",
            "size": 3
         }
      }
   }
```

but it is giving me the tags and its count individually of each question

like this -

```
 "aggregations": {
      "Question1_TAGS": {

         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "clean",
               "doc_count": 34
            },
            {
               "key": "faculty",
               "doc_count": 34
            },
            {
               "key": "staff",
               "doc_count": 21
            }
         ]
      },
      "Question3_TAGS": {

         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "good class",
               "doc_count": 35
            },
            {
               "key": "library",
               "doc_count": 22
            },
            {
               "key": "sports",
               "doc_count": 22
            }
         ]
      },
      "Question2_TAGS": {

         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "Nice class",
               "doc_count": 40
            },
            {
               "key": "Clean",
               "doc_count": 37
            },
            {
               "key": "faculty",
               "doc_count": 31
            }
         ]
      }
```

but i need the common tags from all three questions as shown below.

tagStr : clean ,doc_count :6

tagStr : faculty,doc_count :4

tagStr : study,doc_count :2

it would be very thankful if anyone could help me on this .
Thanks in advance !! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this by using a single `terms` aggregation with a `script` that joins your three arrays like this

```
"aggs": {
  "Question_TAGS": {
     "terms": {
        "script": "doc['question1.tags.tagStr'].values + doc['question2.tags.tagStr'].values + doc['question2.tags.tagStr'].values",
        "size": 3
     }
  }
```

}

That way all `tagStr` fields will be joined into a single array on which the `terms` aggregation will run. Give it a try.

Comment: i just need to ask one more thing for this i had to enable groovy scripts tag in elasticsearch.yml , do it has some performance issues with elastic search ?

Comment: Yes, by running scripts you take a performance hit. Another solution would be to create another array in your documents where you join all three arrays together, then you could use a single `terms` aggregation on that new array and no scripting.

Comment: okay , do scripting changes the internal storage structure of elastic search also ? like elastic search stores document based on inverted index . so scripting changes that implementation also ??

Comment: or any other drawbacks that scripting gives us ?

Comment: No, the internal structure is not changed as far as I know. Scripting simply runs at search time and operates on the stored data, that's why it is a bit less performant. I would advise to do as much work as possible at indexing time to prevent heavy operations to be run at search time. If you create that other array of tags containing the three top tags for each document, it doesn't take much space and you can leverage the full power of terms aggregation without scripting.

Comment: Okay okay , Thanks a lot sir really appreciated :)